# How can you make a growing collection in F#

Tags: f#

Is there a collection type in f# that has an "append" method, such that I can add an element to that collection as such:

(pseudo code)

```
let list = [1,2,3,4]
list.append( 5 )
print list
```

result : 1,2,3,4,5

Basically i need a collection that can grow at run time, I cant assume what size it will be. 
I couldn't find a way to do this with list or array in f#

UPDATE: I dont want to create a new list/array every time this will be happening many times. I want to append the already existing collection. I need to use the same name/symbol for the collection. F# doesn't allow me to redeclare or over write a collection, so this wouldnt work:

```
let A = [1,2,3]
let A = A.append 4  or A <- Array.appen A 4
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what You're trying to do. You can grow a list in f# (however, it'll always give You a new list). You can as well append to arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `ResizeArray`:

```
let list = ResizeArray([1;2;3;4])
list.Add( 5 )
```

Comment: I tried 
let list = ResizeArray([1;2;3;4])
list.Add( 5 )
printfn "%A" list

and I get :   seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...]
although I was able to access list.[4]

Comment: `ResizeArray` is just a built-in alias for `System.Generic.Collections.List<'t>`.  The `%O` format specifier notices when input is a non-F#-specific `IEnumerable<'t>` and pretty-prints the first few elements, not-unreasonably prefixing with `seq`.

Comment: If you want more out of `ResizeArray`, leverage the `ICollection` or the `IList` interface. The first provides countability and synchronization, the other gives indexing and the ability to add or remove items at any position. E.g.
`let list = ResizeArray[1..4] in list.Add 5; list.Count`, which returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what You want achieve has little to do with functional approach. I wouldn't hesitate to use standard .NET List for that.

Regarding Your update: 
Since the lists are immutable, it's not that a new list is created every time You're prepending an element to a list. This is much smarter than copying whole existing list.

Comment: Sorry I just learned F# and dont know anything about .NET. 
what do you mean use standard .NET list? do you mean use another language, or is there a different type of List I can use within f#

about update: I want to permanently modify a global collection such that it has a new element, so that I can access that new element from a different scope. effectively I want to dynamically allocate new memory for the new element.

Comment: OK I get it now, ResizeArray is an alias for type List<T'> which I guess is different the regular F# list

Comment: Yes, I also didn't new, that ResizeArray is alias for List<T>. Youre right that it's different than native f# list. The List<T> is a standard and most commonly used collection in .NET. Since f# also is working on .net platform it can use it as well. It's just that f# is functional first, that's why it has it's own list suited better for functional approach.